# Is it possible for the user to disable certain sites from appearing in hot network questions?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

I really admire the creativity in some questions from [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour), but I prefer to not see imaginary questions mixed in with real ones.

Is there a way I can remove those, without removing the whole HNQ panel? (I think some HTML blocker plugins will remove the whole thing).

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog wow that was quick! Thank you!

Comment: Some would argue they are far from imaginary questions (but disguised as such)...

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q perhaps - they're certainly fascinating. PS what is 'forgot Clay Shirky_q'

Comment: @stevec I asked him before without a reply, my best guess it's something to do with [this](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2012/apr/19/clay-shirky-q-and-a).